# How to bind List<> to dataGridview C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to window application.
I have written a code to read files inside a folder and read it line by line and find some string and display its count to dataGridView.
I wanted to fill a dataGridview which is not working.
I have tried different ways over the internet but none of them are working.
I know that I might be making a silly mistake.
My code is as follow

```
  public class FileDetail
    {
        public  string filename;
        public int openConnectionCount;
        public int closeConnectionCount;
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int openConnectionCount = 0;
        int closeConnectionCount = 0;
        List<FileDetail> fileDetails =new List<FileDetail>();
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            FileDetail fileDetail =new FileDetail();
            fileDetail.filename = file;
            // Read the file as one string.
            using (StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(file))
            {

                string line;
                while ((line = myFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains(" OpenConnection()")) openConnectionCount++;
                    if (line.Contains(" CloseConnection()")) closeConnectionCount++;
                }
                fileDetail.openConnectionCount = openConnectionCount;
                fileDetail.closeConnectionCount = closeConnectionCount;
            }
            fileDetails.Add(fileDetail);
            openConnectionCount = 0;
            closeConnectionCount = 0;
        }



        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("filename", "File Name");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("openConnectionCount", "Open Connection");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("closeConnectionCount", "close Connection");

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "filename";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "openConnectionCount";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "closeConnectionCount";

        var filenamesList = new BindingList<FileDetail>(fileDetails); // <-- BindingList
        dataGridView1.DataSource = filenamesList;


        //dataGridView1.DataSource = fileDetails;




        //dataGridView1.b

        //foreach (var fileDetail in fileDetails)
        //{
        //    label1.Text += "FileName:=" + fileDetail.filename + "\t Open Connection:= " +
        //                   fileDetail.openConnectionCount + "\t close connection:=" +
        //                   fileDetail.closeConnectionCount+"\n";
        //}
    }
```

### Edit:-

I have followed some link for the same
[How to bind list to dataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228539/how-to-bind-list-to-datagridview)
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharplanguage/thread/766c7b46-6431-4ec1-8e74-50f718c6606b

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Data binding only work with Set/Get Properties, not public field.

Try to change your `FileDetail` like this :

```
public class FileDetail
{
    public  string filename { get; set; }
    public int openConnectionCount { get; set; }
    public int closeConnectionCount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to auto generate columns of datagridview then you can use it as

```
public class FileDetail
{
    [DisplayName("File Name")]    
    public  string filename { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Open Connection")]    
    public int openConnectionCount { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("close Connection")]    
    public int closeConnectionCount { get; set; }
}
```

more you can use List as Datasource without Binding source as

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = fileDetails.ToArray();
```

for more information you can check this link
[Bind List of Class objects as Datasource to DataGridView](http://www.codeplussoft.com/Pages/bindclasslistdgv)