# Best Way to Display/Sort List Items in C#

Tags: c#, sorting

I decided a short time ago to teach myself C#, and have spent the last 3 months slowly learning many of the controls for a Windows Form application. I know this might seem like an easy question, but at this point I do not know which direction to go for my needs.  Can someone give me little direction?

To teach myself C#, I have created an app for personal use that basically mimics Quicken.  Up until now, I have just figured out how to save my CHECK#, PAYEE, ETC. fields for a check as a list-item, and then save that as a CSV...like I said, still learning here.  What I would like to do is take the next step and load the CSV file and display all checks in a table format, maybe with alternating background colors, with sort-able headers (CHECK #, PAYEE, AMOUNT, BALANCE) that I click on to sort by the specific column.  I don't want to get into databases yet, so can someone point me in the direction of a control and control tutorial that I can walk through?  I was thinking of loading the CSV into a String List and then sending it to a ListView container, but I am unfamiliar with that tool or even if it is the right tool for the job.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is everyone down-voting me?  Aren't you here to help?

Comment: That's probably why: http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Your question is too open ended

Comment: I disagree.  According to the FAQ, my question was perfectly fine.  As quoted here..."You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."  Many thanks to James, for actually participating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a Data Grid.  This question shows how to bind a Data Grid to a List (as opposed to a data source from a database for example):

[How to bind list to dataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228539/how-to-bind-list-to-datagridview)