# How To Bind List To DataGridView Win Form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have the following code but the DataGridView is showing me empty rows. I can't find the solution. What am I doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
namespace Domain.Repository
{
    public class JenisTransaksi_Repository
    {
        #region Private Variables
        private Int64 _Id_JenisTransaksi1 { get; set; }
        private string _Kode_JenisTransaksi1 { get; set; }
        private string _Nama_JenisTransaksi1 { get; set; }
        #endregion                

        #region Load Data
        public List<JenisTransaksi_Repository> RetrieveAllJenisTransaksi()
        {
            using (var _Ent = new DB_INVENTORYEntities())
            {
                List<JenisTransaksi_Repository> _List = new List<JenisTransaksi_Repository>();
                _List = (from x in _Ent.Tb_JenisTransaksi
                 select new JenisTransaksi_Repository
                 {
                     _Id_JenisTransaksi1 = x.Id_JenisTransaksi,
                     _Kode_JenisTransaksi1 = x.Kode_JenisTransaksi,
                     _Nama_JenisTransaksi1 = x.Nama_JenisTransaksi
                 }).ToList();

                return _List;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bind to Grid :

```
#region Bind To Grid
public void BindAllJenisTransaksi(DataGridView _DataGridView)
{
     var bindingList = new BindingList<JenisTransaksi_Repository>(RetrieveAllJenisTransaksi());
     var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
     _DataGridView.DataSource = source;
}
#endregion
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind list to dataGridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228539/how-to-bind-list-to-datagridview)

Comment: What does your JenisTransaksi_Repository class look like?  Are those members that you're setting properties or fields?  Only properties can be bound so, if they're fields, you won't see them.

Comment: Also, make sure that the properties in your `JenisTransaksi_Repository` class are public

Comment: @rwisch45 thanks, i change the private variables in 'JenisTransaksi_Repository' to public, that's works