# How To Display List on DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid

```
List<string> f = new List<string>();
        f.Add("Hello");
        DataGrid1.ItemsSource = f;
```

It's display to me a one column with the header "Length" and inside the length of the word.
How do i solve it?

Comment: The data binding will display properties of the object, in this case Length is a property of String.  You should create your own class with a property for each column you want in the grid, then bind to a List<MyClass>     E.g. class MyClass { public string Name { get; set; } }

Comment: you can also do this using a `BindingList` here is an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228539/how-to-bind-list-to-datagridview

Answer (score 2):

```
_dgCars.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn makeColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
makeColumn.DataPropertyName = "Make";
makeColumn.HeaderText = "The Car's Make";

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn modelColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
modelColumn.DataPropertyName = "Model";
modelColumn.HeaderText = "The Car's Model";

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn yearColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
yearColumn.DataPropertyName = "Year";
yearColumn.HeaderText = "The Car's Year";

_dgCars.Columns.Add(makeColumn);
_dgCars.Columns.Add(modelColumn);
_dgCars.Columns.Add(yearColumn);

BindingList<Car> cars = new BindingList<Car>();

cars.Add(new Car("Ford", "Mustang", 1967));
cars.Add(new Car("Shelby AC", "Cobra", 1965));
cars.Add(new Car("Chevrolet", "Corvette Sting Ray", 1965));

_dgCars.DataSource = cars;
```

use System.Collections.Generic in your namespace ,although list is good but advantage of using BindingList is that you can also do further modifications,updation in datagrid where u can't do this in list...Hope this might work for you

Answer (score 0):

Either define your own custom column or build composite objects.

But you should better use another control like a `ListBox` which has the same API.