# How to load <list> data into dataGridView in c#

Tags: c#

I already have rows and columns for `dataGridView` in c# widows form application.  How can I display the data into `datagridview..whole the data are in a list.  Now, I want to load the list into datagridview.. I am new to c# and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Some relevant code may be helpful and demonstrate what you tried already.

Comment: looks like duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228539/how-to-bind-list-to-datagridview?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

In your question you didn't mention which type of list you use.
Try to do this using data table.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
foreach(var oItem in YourList)
{
     dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { oItem.FirstName, oItem.LastName });
}
myDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: OP stated that the data is in a `List<T>` - how does this help them bind the `List<T>` to the `DataGridView`?

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you want to use a list as the datasource.

```
List<myObject> oblst = new List<myObject>;
//insert into the list
datagridview.DataSource = oblst;
```

Removed `datagridview.DataBind();`

Comment: The `DataGridView` class does not have `DataBind` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any collection that implements `IEnumerable` and simply assign it as DataSource to your DataGridView , like

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = myCollection;
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is brought here by Google/etc, use a BindingList

Answer (score -1):

You can use ToArray() to convert your list. Say if your DataGridView named as *yourdataGridView* and the available list named as *yourList* then

```
yourdataGridView.DataSource = yourList.ToArray();
```

Comment: The `DataGridView` class does not have `DataBind` method. Also, what's the point in copying the List another array?