# How to fill devExpress datagridview with Mongo DB data

Tags: c#, mongodb, devexpress

I am trying to fill DevExpress datagridview with data from Mongo db using c#.

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried and show us some code?

Comment: Provide us some code before we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

It should work similar with another [Traditional Data Binding Methods](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2385), but in case of mangodb I suggest you to use BindingList or BindingSource to bind data with the [GridControl.DataSource](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_DataSourcetopic) Property.

You can get data from database as Collection of class and then bind it to the Grid Control:

```
var con = new   MongoConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoDB"].ConnectionString);     

    var server = MongoServer.Create(con);
    var db = server.GetDatabase(con.DatabaseName);
    var collection = db.GetCollection<Post>("post");
```

then modify the data which you get from the database and assign it the GridControl.

Reference these for more information:
[BIND DATA TO ASP.NET GRIDVIEW USING MONGODB](https://sanmukhait.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/programming-with-c/)
[Using MongoDB from C#](http://blog.dynamicprogrammer.com/2009/11/10/UsingMongoDBFromC.aspx)
[A MongoDB Tutorial using C# and ASP.NET MVC](http://A%20MongoDB%20Tutorial%20using%20C#%20and%20ASP.NET%20MVC)

[C# and .NET MongoDB Driver](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/)

Answer (score 0):

These are two different problems.

Whatever the way you're retrieving your data from your mongo db instance, what you need to do is to build a List and then bind it to your dataGridView  datasource property (you'll find on StackOverflow plenty of help regarding this problem such as this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228539/how-to-bind-list-to-datagridview).