# After changing DataSource, why does DataGridView show rows only after sorting?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, oracle12c

I am trying to make a DataGridView control get populated from a DataTable, that itself gets filled with the results of a sql query on a Oracle database. This should happen after double-clicking the table name from a ListBox control.

This works fine the first time I double-click a table name, but the second time it will only show the column names and no rows.

What I have discovered is that sorting the DataGridView based on any column will cause the rows to suddenly appear, which makes me suspect some kind of graphical/rendering glitch.

Is this expected behavior?

```cs
// event handler for ListBox
private void tables_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)    
{
    // tables is a ListBox populated with table names
    int index = this.tables.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);     
    String table_name;
    if (index != System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NoMatches)
    {
        // reusing the DataTable
        dt.Reset();     
        table_name =tables.Items[index].ToString();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        // case sensitive
        cmd.CommandText = String.Format(@"select * from ""{0}""",table_name);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
        da.Fill(dt);
        dt.TableName = table_name;
        label7.Text = table_name;
        // these three lines don't actually accomplish anything in this case
        table.DataSource = null;    
        table.Rows.Clear();
        table.DataSource = dt;

        // uncommenting these lines produces the expected behavior 
        //DataGridViewColumn c = table.Columns[0];      
        //table.Sort(c,System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending);
    }
}
```

[After second double-click(without sorting)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6ySd.png)

[After second double-click(with sorting)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvFLM.png)

Comment: Curious: Why don't you go for the simpler version : `table_name = tables.SelectedItem.ToString();` Did you disable the ListBox? Did you try a `table.Refresh()`?

Comment: @TaW Thanks for the suggestion. I did try Refresh(), Update() and other methods but sorting seems to be the only thing that works. Also the ListBox is always enabled so that subsequent tables can be selected.

Comment: Hm, this sounds weird; I sure there must be something else going on.. Any other properties of the DGV you have set? VitualMode?

Comment: Try using BindingSource. 
`BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
source.DataSource = dt
dataGridView.Datasource = source;`

Comment: I did set Visible and Enabled to false, and set them to true only after connecting to the database, but it behaves the same way. AutoGenerateColumns is set by default to true. I'll try to work with sorted rows, since sorting does not affect the DataTable.

Comment: Already tried BindingSource and got the same behaviour, but thanks anyway.

Comment: May be your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228539/how-to-bind-list-to-datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is caused by the `DataTable.Reset` call.

Although it's not your code problem (most likely a bug in `DataTable` or `DataView`), I would suggest using `Clear` method instead of `Reset` or creating a new `DataTable` instance.

Comment: Yes `dt = new DataTable();` instead of `dt.Reset()` did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but using VBA. Attached is my solution.

Description of stuff...
CSV_IO_INSTANCE is a class that has a data table DATA_TABLE in it. I need to reload new csv data into this instance of the DATA_TABLE and then refresh.

Code...

```
    Private Sub SHARED_CREATE_DATA_TABLE()
    Try
        DATA_GRID_VIEW_CSV_IO.DataSource = CSV_IO_INSTANCE.DATA_TABLE
        '^BIND DGV TO LOCAL INSTANCE OF THE CSV_IO TABLE.
        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        'BUG FIX 011 - SEE BUG_FIX_LOG.txt FOR DOCUMENTATION.
        Dim COLUMN_BUG_FIX As DataGridViewColumn = DATA_GRID_VIEW_CSV_IO.Columns(0)
        '^CREATE A COLUMN TO DO BUG FIX ON.
        COLUMN_BUG_FIX.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
        '^CHANGE ITS SORT MODE.
        DATA_GRID_VIEW_CSV_IO.Sort(COLUMN_BUG_FIX, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        '^SORT.
        DATA_GRID_VIEW_CSV_IO.Sort(COLUMN_BUG_FIX, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)
        '^JUST ONE SORT WONT DO IT.
        COLUMN_BUG_FIX.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
        '^CHANGE BACK TO AUTO SORT TO GET RID OF THAT SORT ARROW IN THE COLUMN HEADER.
        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Catch EXCEPTION As Exception
        CSV_IO_INSTANCE.LOG.WRITE_LINE("Exception in the SHARED_CREATE_DATA_TABLE subroutine.", EXCEPTION)
        '^WRITE ERROR MESSAGE TO THE EVENT_LOG INSTANCE (LOG) IN THE CSV_IO INSTANCE.
    End Try
End Sub
```

EDIT:

I found some of the posts in this forum post helped steer me in the right direction:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/16398f0c-9687-42aa-8678-e742a43c00c5/reset-the-sort-status-after-reloading-a-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols

EDIT X2:

Ok, the first solution did not fully work. While it removed the sort icon on the column header it left the column sorted. I reworked it with a bit of help from this link:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1a9350da-3575-4f79-b708-4277e4d6a240/how-to-force-datagridview-back-to-an-unsorted-state?forum=vbgeneral

Now I have a working model, I'm using a binding source because of its RemoveSort feature. I call FLUSH_DGV_AND_BS then I repopulate my data table then I call BIND_DGV_TO_BS and this works great.

```
Private Sub BIND_DGV_TO_BS()
    BINDING_SOURCE.DataSource = CSV_IO_INSTANCE.DATA_TABLE
    '^BIND DATASET TO THE INSTANCES DATA TABLE
    DATA_GRID_VIEW_CSV_IO.DataSource = BINDING_SOURCE
    'BUG FIX 011 - SEE BUG_FIX_LOG.txt FOR DOCUMENTATION.--------------------------------------
    Dim COLUMN_BUG_FIX As DataGridViewColumn = DATA_GRID_VIEW_CSV_IO.Columns(0)
    '^CREATE A COLUMN TO DO BUG FIX ON.
    DATA_GRID_VIEW_CSV_IO.Sort(COLUMN_BUG_FIX, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
    '^SORT IN ORDER TO CAUSE THE BUG TO GO AWAY.
    BINDING_SOURCE.RemoveSort()
    '^THEN REMOVE THE SORT TO PUT IT BACK TO ITS RAW DATA VIEW.
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Sub
Private Sub FLUSH_DGV_AND_BS()
    With BINDING_SOURCE
        .DataSource = Nothing
        '^REMOVE THE PREVIOUS BINDINGS.
    End With
    CSV_IO_INSTANCE.DATA_TABLE.Clear()
    '^CLEAR OUT THE DATA TABLE.
End Sub
```