# Is there a way to bind individual columns on DataGridView to a Table in a Database using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

So you can bind various fields to a `ComboBox` like this so that the selected value of the `ComboBox` will then autofill the text fields.

```
var SID = Convert.ToInt32(cbosSID.Text);
using (Entities2 db = new Entities2())
{
    var student = (from a in db.Students where a.SID == SID select a).First();
    txtsFName.Text = student.FName;
    txtsLName.Text = student.LName;
    txtsPhone.Text = student.Phone;
    txtsAdd1.Text = student.Add1;
    txtsAdd2.Text = student.Add2;
    txtsState.Text = student.State;
    txtsSuburb.Text = student.Suburb;
    txtsPost.Text = student.Postcode;
    dteDOB.Value = student.DOB;
    dteStart.Value = student.SDate;
}
```

**Can you do the same thing to a `DataGridView` with its individual columns?**

I've added two columns to the `DataGridView` , Student ID and Mark. I tried to do it using `editDataGridView.Columns[course.SID].DataPropertyName = "clmSID";` but that doesn't work.

```
private void cboeCID_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var CID = Convert.ToInt32(cboeCID.Text);
    using (var db = new Entities2())
    {
        var course = (from a in db.Student_Course where a.CID == CID select a).First();
        editDataGridView.Columns[course.SID].DataPropertyName = "clmSID";
        editDataGridView.Columns[course.Mark].DataPropertyName = "clmMark";
    };
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need something like the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228539/how-to-bind-list-to-datagridview

Comment: What do you want to show in grid, a list or a single record? You selected `.First` from a query, but it seems you need to show a list in grid. Can you explain more about your requirement?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I want to be able to automatically fill the datagridview columns in a similar manner to the first method. When the selected value of the combobox is changed, the values in the datagridview will change with it. Then I'll get a save/edit button to save any information change made on the datagridview back into the database.

Comment: **•** You need a list, so using `First` is incorrect. **•** To show data in grid, it's enough to set the result of query as `DataSource` of grid. **•** Also if you need to change data in grid and save them, you should not use `db` in a `using`.

Comment: When you create context this way `using (var db = new Entities2())` you will loose the ability of change-tracking using your context. If you only want to show data in grid it's OK. But if you want to show data and also edit and save changes, you should not define context this way. Instead you should create a field of type `Entities2 db;` at form level and initialize it in `Load` event of form: `db = new Entities2()`. Then use it to load data: `var data = db.Student_Course.Where(a=> a.CID == CID).ToList()` then assign `data` to `DataSource` of grid. When you want to save, call `db.SaveChanges`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this tips:

- To show a `List<T>` in `DataGridView`, it's enough to assign it to `DataSource` of grid.
- When you assign `List<T>` to a `DataGridView` which had not defined columns for it, by default the grid will show all browsable properties of `List<T>`
- To show only some of column, you can consider this solutions:

  ○ You can define columns using designer or code and set `DataPropertyName` property of the column to the property name which you want to show in column. This way only those columns will be added to `DataGridView`.

  ○ You can let the columns to be generated automatically and then remove or hide those ones that you don't want to show.

- When you create context in a using `block`, you will loose the ability of change-tracking using your context. If you only want to show data in grid it's OK. But if you want to show data and also edit and save changes, you should not define context this way. Instead you should create a field of type of your context at form level and initialize it in Load event of form and use it for load and save data.

Here I post a sample using `Category` and `Product` to be more general.

```
Category: Id, Name  
Product : Id, Name, CategoryId, Price, Description
Relation: Categry [1]---[*] Product
```

In the below code, first we define `db` as a filed of `Form` and will initialize it in `Load` event of form. This way, it can track changes. Also when perform data binding with a `ComboBox` this way:

```
SampleDbEntities db;
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    db = new TestDBEntities();
    var categories = db.Category.ToList();
    this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
    this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    this.comboBox1.DataSource = categories;
}
```

Then handle `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `ComboBox` and load `Product` entities based on selected value of `ComboBox`. In the below code, we only will show "Price" and "Name" columns in `DataGridView`:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.comboBox1.SelectedValue == null)
        return;
    var desiredColumns = new[] { "Price", "Name" };
    var id = (int)this.comboBox1.SelectedValue;
    var data = db.Product.Where(x => x.CategoryId == id).ToList();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                 .Where(x => !desiredColumns.Contains(x.DataPropertyName))
                 .ToList().ForEach(x => { x.Visible = false; });
}
```

To save changes, handle `Click` event of a button and write such code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```